# managing rails controllers

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a home page HomeController this loads the home view which has some header content and other html at the top of the page. I also have a storyBoard below all that content on the page, then some other home page html content. Now the storyboard has a model view controller also. My question is how would I get my view to load into that storyboard area on the home page. Would I need to communicate from my HomeController to my StoryBoard controller to place the StoryBoard view into the home view area for where storyboard is meant to show.

I'm not sure how to go about setting up the relationships between the two.

**UPDATED WITH CODE.**

This code it just really the scaffolding code generated by rails. Hopefuly this will help make clear what I'm trying to do. I just want to be able to render my storyboard into the home view storyboard div tag.

**HomeController**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

end
```

**Home view**

```
<body>
<div id="description">
    <div id="info">
        <p class="title">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis</p>
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="soryboard">
  // add story board view here
</div>
<div id="section2">
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo</p>
</div>

</body>
```

**StoryBoard Controller**

```
class StoryboardsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /storyboards
  # GET /storyboards.json
  def index
    @storyboards = Storyboard.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @storyboards }
    end
  end

  # GET /storyboards/1
  # GET /storyboards/1.json
  def show
    @storyboard = Storyboard.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @storyboard }
    end
  end

  # GET /storyboards/new
  # GET /storyboards/new.json
  def new
    @storyboard = Storyboard.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @storyboard }
    end
  end

  # GET /storyboards/1/edit
  def edit
    @storyboard = Storyboard.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /storyboards
  # POST /storyboards.json
  def create
    @storyboard = Storyboard.new(params[:storyboard])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @storyboard.save
        format.html { redirect_to @storyboard, notice: 'Storyboard was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @storyboard, status: :created, location: @storyboard }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @storyboard.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /storyboards/1
  # PUT /storyboards/1.json
  def update
    @storyboard = Storyboard.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @storyboard.update_attributes(params[:storyboard])
        format.html { redirect_to @storyboard, notice: 'Storyboard was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @storyboard.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /storyboards/1
  # DELETE /storyboards/1.json
  def destroy
    @storyboard = Storyboard.find(params[:id])
    @storyboard.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to storyboards_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

**StoryBoard view**

```
<h1>Listing storyboard</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Image url</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Link</th>
    <th>Width</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @storyboards.each do |storyboard| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= storyboard.image_url %></td>
    <td><%= storyboard.title %></td>
    <td><%= storyboard.description %></td>
    <td><%= storyboard.category %></td>
    <td><%= storyboard.link %></td>
    <td><%= storyboard.width %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', storyboard %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_storyboard_path(storyboard) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', storyboard, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Storyboard', new_storyboard_path %>
```

Comment: Please provide a snippet of the code. It'd help use figure out what you are trying to do. I'm not sure what your goal is just from reading your explanation.

Comment: Ok Leo just provided code but again its just the scaffolding code that rails generates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#render` in Rails allows you render any template:

```
# home/index.html.erb
# ...
<div id="soryboard">
 <%= render :template => "storyboard/index" %>
</div>
# ...
```

**However** you must make sure that all data used in that template is also available in the 
HomeController action.

---

**In addition** you might want make more use of the application layout file if you havent already. Because thats usually the place where things like the header and the footer go
A typical application layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
<body id="<%= params[:controller].gsub("/","_")+"_"+params[:action] %>">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
    </div>

    <!-- renders the corresponding template -->
    <%= yield %> 

    <div id="footer"> 
      <small>&copy; <%= Time.now.year %></small>
    </div>    
  </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But wont this remove the content in my Home view. I just want to keep my content in my home view and render the storyBoard view into a div below all the home view content. But that storyBoard view has a controller with all my crud methods like show edit destroy ....   how would I make sure  all data used in that template is also available in the HomeController action

Comment: 1) No it wont - 2) You can just render that view - 3) For the data to be available you need the model methods and some instance variables - e.g. `@storyboards = StoryBoard.find :all`

Comment: When I try to add the render method to the index.erb file for the home view I get this error. Missing partial storyboards/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:

Comment: Great thanks that did the trick. So StoryBoard.find :all or StoryBoard.all is finding all the entries in the StoryBoard model. Is that correct?